# Referencing constants from Module

Tags: ruby

In a tutorial, there are examples querying constants using `const_get`:

```
class This
end

p Module.const_get('This').new
```

and

```
A_CONSTANT = 42
p Module.const_get('A_CONSTANT')
```

1. I can't see any module definition. Why is `Module` used? Why isn't `const_get('This')` or `self.const_get('This')` enough? The class where all this is written in is `Object`, ancestor of `BasicObject`.
2. Does the fact that `This` is a constant mean that it holds the class definition inside of it? Like as it just could hold the number `42`? Or to be clearer, is it the same as:

   ```
   This = class
   end
   ```

   like an unnamed method so I can write `p This` and get the class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some nice knowledge you have acquired. But I don't know why are you mentioning metaprogramming in your title, when your question is all about constants. Metaprogramming is [something else](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class).

In any case, `#const_get` is an instance method of `Module` class, so it won't work at the top level, where the implicit receiver is of `Object` class. When you write

```
class Foo; end
```

Constant `Foo` gets added to `Object`:

```
Object::Foo #=> Foo
Object::Bar #=> error (we didn't define constant Bar)
```

This constant is available also in other classes, such as

```
Module::Foo #=> Foo, but with a warning
Array::Foo #=> same Foo with the same warning
Fixnum::Foo #=> ditto
```

In other words, your `Foo` defined at toplevel is visible from almost every module. But accessing toplevel constants like this is frowned upon, as this is often not what the programmer intended. You can indeed see that the constant is defined on `Object`:

```
Object.constants( false ).include? :Foo #=> true
```

and not on eg. `Module`:

```
Module.constants( false ).include? :Foo #=> false
```

However, if you use `#const_get`, the warning message is suppressed and you may come to think that `Module::Foo` actually exists:

```
Module.const_get( :Foo ) #=> Foo
```

It doesn't.